# How do I get R to find dbConnect function?

Tags: r, rsqlite, dbconnect

[image: Screen image 1]

Hi,
I seem to be having trouble with RSQLite and dbConnect. DBI and RSQlite appear to be active in the packages but continue to receive the message that the dbConnect function isn't found. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

ajamsterdam

Comment: start a fresh new session of R and try again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: As you are rendering an Rmd, check that the document includes a `library(DBI)`